# slow scrolling on Nativescript ListView

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

The following ListView on android has very choppy scrolling:

```
<ListView [items]="sites">
  <ng-template let-item="item">
    <Label [text]="item.station_name"></Label>    
  </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

If I change the label to some static text, the scrolling is no longer choppy:

```
<ListView [items]="sites">
  <ng-template let-item="item">
    <Label [text]="static text"></Label>    
  </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Each site object from the sites being iterated over has about 50 fields. In this example I'm only using the station_name key.

Any idea how to improve the scrolling to be smooth? I've tried piping sites to a function that calls map on each site returning only the station_name field, but it's still choppy.

Comment: This scrolls smothly: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=OF2tzY If you're trying to display 50 fields, maybe you should make a single Label/TextView and add `\n` between the lines. It's probably quicker than creating and changing 50 labels

Comment: @Bass thanks for setting up that playground! The problem only manifests when nesting the ListView inside a FlexboxLayout. For instance if you replace GridLayout with FlexBoxLayout in your playground the scrolling becomes choppy (even when iterating over objects with a single field): https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=tYPIY6&v=2 Any ideas why?

Comment: That's probably the issue. It's probably recalculating the layout on scroll, which is why it's choppy. If you set a fixed width/height, it's smooth again: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=tYPIY6&v=3 I suggest you use a GridLayout with a `*` for a ListView, so it expands, or fixed width/height.

Comment: You don't even have to wrap ListView with any layout unless you want to add any more components on the Page.

Comment: as @manoj said, you are just showing ListView on entire page and it will scroll by itself. Need not wrap it within any other control